# Can anyone please explain the meaning of vector resonances in the scenario of particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology

I was reading some material on Particle physics and I came across the sentence:

> pseudoscalar D and B meson states and the corresponding vector resonances D* and B*.

What are vector resonances?

Source: Phenomenology of heavy meson Chiral Lagrangians by Casalbuoni,Bartolomeo,Gatto,Feruglio and Nardulli. 7th page from the introduction.

Comment: It is always better to mention the name of the source the quote is excerpted from as it helps to clear the context of the quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudoscalar and vector are terms that indicate the total spin and parity of the resonance. Pseudoscalar particles have spin 0 and parity -1, while vector particles have spin 1 and parity -1.

The Particle Data Review lists your particles as:

- $D^\pm\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 0^-$
- $D^0\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 0^-$
- $D^*(2007)^0\qquad \qquad 1^-$
- $D^*(2010)^\pm\qquad\qquad 1^-$
- $B^\pm\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 0^-$
- $B^0\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 0^-$
- $B^*\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 1^-$

K.A. Olive et al. (Particle Data Group), Chin. Phys. C, 38, 090001 (2014) and 2015 update. ([link to the mesons table](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/tables/rpp2015-qtab-mesons.pdf)).